# VS C++ multiple projects to one dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll

I have a solution with multiple projects (Visual Studio 2010) that compile to static libraries (some compile to dll but naturally generate also a library). All written in C++. I want to provide my solution packed in one dll. So I want to generate from all projects one DLL, that is pack them all into one DLL, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: How about wrapping these libraries so that unified interface is provided?

Comment: A fuller explanation of **why** might help. But are you looking for providing *one* dll and *one* lib file along with the headers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best way to do this, but it'll work:

1. Create the DLL project that amalgamates the rest of the libraries
2. Statically link all the other libraries to this project
3. Write forwarding functions for each interface function from the other libraries
4. Export these forwarding functions from your DLL